# Equivalent of TypeScript Record in Flow?

Tags: javascript, typescript, flowtype

TypeScript provides the utility type `Record` and I am looking for its equivalent in Flow.

I tried: `{ [key: KeyType]: Value }` but that definition has a different semantic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent is almost identical to TypeScript:

```
// @flow

type Record<T, V> = {
  [T]: V
}
```

Pulling the example from the TypeScript docs:

```
type ThreeStringProps = Record<'prop1' | 'prop2' | 'prop3', string>

const test: ThreeStringProps = {
  prop1: 'test',
  prop2: 'test',
  prop3: 'test',
}

// Fails because prop3 is not a string
const failingTest: ThreeStringProps = {
  prop1: 'test',
  prop2: 'test',
  prop3: 123,
}

// Fails because `prop4` isn't a valid property
const failingTest2: ThreeStringProps = {
  prop1: 'test',
  prop2: 'test',
  prop3: 'test',
  prop4: 'test',
}
```

You can see this in action at [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AJSwMawBOAJgDwAqANKAGoB8oAvKAN6KigDalAugC56iAL7J02UJQAWxLFgDKKYgEsAdgHMACsVgYAzizyESFAOQZdGAIxnQAH1AWrAJjuPnegMxna+5eoaDJygiERq-qAoWP5CMnKKAZo6eoasHFyWetZCZtH+viFZGC65+SiFmVZeZTEV1KLI4ZGQAIYq0IGUdXGy8kqqyVZp7EVWOU7llaDFpZN108U1oNYuXg1iYbARKKBtHV11c-H9SdrDRhkz47UFDVV6c3kL99fet-VjegAsH2aNQA).

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there a way we can enforce `ThreeStringProps` to exactly declare `prop1`, `prop2`, and `prop3`? 

Comment: That I don't know, I'm not sure if it's possible with Flow or not

Comment: This is now not possible because sum types can no longer be used as object keys